# iojs Harmony Flags on OSX

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to test ES6 features such as arrow functions, classes, and modules on the latest build of io.js (v2.0.2) and OSX Yosemite. I run

```
iojs [filename].js --es_staging --harmony_modules --harmony_arrow_functions
```

but I get complaints like

```
import _ from 'underscore';
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
```

and

```
setTimeout((arg) => {
                 ^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>
```

Am I not running io.js correctly to enable these features?

Comment: As of January 19, [`import` is not supported with the latest V8](https://github.com/nodejs/io.js/issues/518#issuecomment-70570315). But I don't know why the arrow function is not working. I tried with the latest 2.0.2 and works fine.

Comment: Have you considered using Babel, though? `npm install -g babel`, and `babel-node [filename].js`.

Comment: Yes, I've been using Babel, but wanted to try running ES6 features without it. Strange that arrow functions aren't working for me when they're working for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D'oh, the flag needs to come before the filename, so running `iojs --harmony_arrow_functions [filename].js` works.